Django coverage test doesn't seem to run all app tests
I am using coverage to check how much code I have covered with my test suite.
It seems to not run some tests when I run the complete test suite but does if I only run an app.
For example coverage run manage.py test followed by covereage html shows the api app has a 24% coverage.  But when I run coverage run manage.py test api followed by coverage html I get 100% covered.
Why would this happen?
EDIT
@CoffeeBasedLifeForm has identified the issue.  Discovery isn't finding the tests.
The tests are in api>tests>test_views>filename.py
Within the tests directory is __init__.py which contains from .test_views import *
The test_views directory also has an __init__.py containing:
from .administration_api import AdministrationAPIViewTest  # noqa
from .source_api import EventAPIViewTest, SourceAPIViewTest  # noqa
from .study_api import StudyAPIViewTest  # noqa

This structure is working on other apps to pick up the tests.  api is also specified within INSTALLED_APPS.
I do not understand why these tests are not being discovered.

It could be that the test discovery doesn't find your tests if you do not provide a so-called test label (here: api). Can you confirm that the tests run at all if you do manage.py test instead of manage.py test api?

Do you have multiple apps in Django? When you execute manage.py test, by default, this will discover and run tests from any file named test*.py under the current working directory. If you execute manage.py test api, it will discover and run tests from the app api only.

@CoffeeBasedLifeformI added a test I know will fail and it isn't failing when I run for the project, so it would seem the test discovery isn't finding the tests.  But I don't know how to resolve

I ended up moving the tests to another app which was loading.  Couldn't solve it any other way.
Frustrating since this is confusing to another programmer in future
